# Regex split comma except escaped

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

What is the regular expression to split on comma (, and newlines) except if comma is escaped? For example:

```
foo,bar,baz = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

BUT

```
foo,bar\,baz,42 = ["foo", "bar,baz", "42"]
```

Looking to use in javascript#: `value.split(/[\r\n,]+/g);`

Thanks.

Comment: `/(?<!\\),/g` should do it.

Comment: Just do a match on `/(?:(?:\\{2})*\\,|[^,])+/g` instead of splitting.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat lookbehinds only work on Chrome 62+ at the moment.

Comment: @ctwheels I did not knew about it, thanks :-)

Comment: @AniketSahrawat you can follow the [ECMA proposal (TC39) here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind)